# Adding Parameters to setHTTPBody request Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parameters

I am having some trouble adding parameters to my line of code. I have already created a global variable that can access this variable and have NSLog's to verify that it is accessible however I'm having troubling adding the variable.

My line of code is this and i would like to add a tran_id which has already been defined as the variable "ttt" which is an `NSString`. The way I have it in the code right now is not working.

```
 NSLog(@"tran id: %@", ttt);

[request setHTTPBody:[@"{\n  \"partner_key\": \"VxYkMw3N8E\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl\",\n  \"tran_id\": \"%@\"\n}", ttt dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can set params in the setHTTPBody method, what you need is to have a NSStringWithFormat before:

```
NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n  \"partner_key\": \"VxYkMw3N8E\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl\",\n  \"tran_id\": \"%@\"\n}", ttt];

[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Of course, this is the quick-n-dirty method - because you are sending JSON data, consider learning how `NSJSONSerialization` works.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting the error saying "No visible @interface for 'NSMutableURLRequest declares the selector setHTTPBody:dataUsingEncoding' when I use what everybody has given me..?

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! So my problem was that you cannot add a parameter in the request statement so a work around is to create another NSString and plug that in?

Comment: @Neil yes, it's not really a workaround, this is just how you set params to a NSString. But really consider using a NSDictionary, and NSJSONSerialization, your code will be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use stringWithFormat:

```
[request setHTTPBody:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n  \"partner_key\": \"VxYkMw3N8E\",\n  \"auth_token\": \"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl\",\n  \"tran_id\": \"%@\"\n}", ttt]
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I doubt you need the `\n`s and the whitespace in there - they are usually only there to make it more human-readable. That would make your format string somewhat easier to decipher:

```
[request setHTTPBody:
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"partner_key\":\"VxYkMw3N8E\",\"auth_token\":\"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl\",\"tran_id\":\"%@\"}", ttt]
    dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are formatting your parameters to a string too early. Once it's formatted to a string the values cannot easily be modified and new parameters cannot be added.

Instead, you need to collect these parameters is an `NSMutableDictionary` and only convert it to JSON when you're ready to send the request.

Therefore create an `parameters` property:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSMutableDictionay *parameters;
```

and don't forget to allocate it in the `init` method.  Then when it's time to send the request, generate the JSON using:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters 
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&error];
```

Comment: I have already formatted the string in an earlier part of the code, I just did not upload it since its very long, I'm just having trouble formatting that statement to send in the data.

Comment: @Neil you said you wanted to change a value in the formatted string?

Comment: Yes, in that statement the variable, ttt, changes after each run from the data back in a previous json reqeust. I have to use that variable i get back to make another json request

Comment: @Neil Therefore you need to keep the values in a dictionary, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this really hard on yourself by using this big long string for setting up the HTTP Body. Use a dictionary instead:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictionary setObject:@"VxYkMw3N8E" forKey:@"partner_key"];
[dictionary setObject:@"QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl" forKey:@"auth_token"];    



NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];


NSString *jsonString;

if (!jsonData) {
} else {
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}


 [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];
```